# Цикличный таймер обратного отсчета выполнения функции

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно сделать цикличный таймер обратного отсчета который будет выполнять определенную функцию по его окончанию и так снова и снова, и чтобы при обновлении страницы таймер не сбрасывался, короче не зависел от пользователя и работал, не могу реализовать, не хватает знаний

Comment: для каждого пользователя свой? или для всех один?

Comment: Должен работать для всех один

Comment: так время значит на сервере должно идти, нет?

Comment: получается да и чтобы оттуда создавался обратный таймер который каждые, например, 20 секунд в конце исполняет функцию, и делает отсчет заново

Comment: Вам нужны websockets